# which one is correct? "I'm an English teacher and supervisor or I'm an English teacher and a supervisor"

Tags: articles

Which one is correct?

> I'm an English teacher ***and supervisor***
>   I'm an English teacher ***and a supervisor***

Answer (score 2):

The article 'a' isn't necessarily needed. For example, if someone said "*I'm a football player and coach*", that makes sense. They have two roles - they play football, and they coach football.

I'm presuming by "supervisor" you mean a teacher with responsibility for a particular student. I don't feel it is a widely-known term outside of educational institutions. If you were speaking to one of your colleagues I'm sure they would understand "I'm an English teacher and supervisor". However, some might wonder what you are a supervisor of. With the football player and coach example, you'd assume he coached football and not, say, tennis. Your example could sound like you're a "supervisor of English", and I'm not even sure if there is such a thing.

So, to someone who may not understand the job description, you could add the article and say "I'm an English teacher and **a** supervisor", or you could add some detail to make the two roles more distinct, for example, "I'm an English teacher and supervisor to a student".